# Has there ever been a Euros or World Cup champion that never conceded a goal?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup, scoring, euro

Going in to their Euro 2020's semifinal match against Denmark, England haven't conceded a goal. Jordan Pickford, the goalie, has had 5 clean sheets in the tournament so far.

Has there been a World Cup or Euros champion that didn't concede a goal all tournament?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there was no such champion neither in the men's World Cup nor in the men's Euros which didn't concede at least one goal during the tournament.

Even in pre 1976 Euros when championship basically consisted of a semifinal and a final game, champions would always concede at least a single goal.

The best result so far can be attributed to Spain during [Euro 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2012) when they won the tournament and conceded only one goal (in their very first game).

Answer (score 6):

Germany at the [World Cup in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_FIFA_Women%27s_World_Cup) conceded zero goals! Naturally, their goalkeeper Nadine Angerer won Best Goalie of the tournament.